# ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, ora-00979

Why does this work

```
SELECT DISTINCT FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME
FROM books, CUSTOMERS, orders, orderitems
WHERE STATE IN('FL ', 'GA')
GROUP BY orders.order#, firstname, lastname
HAVING SUM(retail*quantity) > 80
```

but when `firstname, lastname` is removed from `group by` it doesn't?

> ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Comment: Why in the world don't you have any join conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case where `firstname, lastname` are removed from the `group by`, you get that error because you're `SELECT`ing a column(s) that aren't in the `GROUP BY` expression, or aren't part of an aggregation/function (i.e. MIN, MAX, AVG, and others).

You could also eliminate the `DISTINCT` as well.

Comment: You probably shouldn't remove the distinct. In any case, removing "distinct" will can the output. If two rows have the same first and last name but differant order# they be repeated if the distinct is removed.

Answer (score 2):

As I can guess

First of all GROUP BY operation is performed and then DISTINCT. In GROUP BY clause you must indicate all non-aggregates . For example you are not permitted to do the following:

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME
FROM EMPLOYEES
GROUP BY HIRE_DATE
```

You should do it by this way:

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME
FROM EMPLOYEES
GROUP BY HIRE_DATE,FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME
```